# SSIS Error Code and Error Column

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Importing text files via SSIS. I have few text files were I'm converting Date Columns using derived column transformation.
I'm redirecting the error rows to a different table.
I get two columns extra namely "ErrorColumn" "ErrorCode" which provides some value. 
My question is what does this value specify , how can I know what is wrong with the error rows that were redirected or failed conversion.
Since this is for reporting I want all the rows to go to the destination table. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Example :

```
ErrorCode   ErrorColumn
-1073442796 4
-1073442796 10
-1073442796 10
-1073442796 10
-1073442796 10
-1073442796 10
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the error code's description, you will need to add a Script Task to your data flow that gets the description and adds it as a new column - [see here for a complete tutorial](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/08/08/SSIS-Nugget_3A00_-Get-error-descriptions.aspx).
Code:

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
    Row.ErrorDescription = _
      Me.ComponentMetaData.GetErrorDescription(Row.ErrorCode)

End Sub
```

As an example, screenshots of my own setup are below:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: [Additional reading material ...](http://informatics.northwestern.edu/blog/edw/2012/01/etl-assistant-getting-error-row-description-and-column-dynamically/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will go through this and try to include it in the workflow.